# Odd happenings of OpenGL Texturing

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am fairly certain my textures are loaded without problem, however, I cannot get them to render!

I enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` in when I initialize GL. I then load the texture with this function:

```
GLuint loadTexture(std::string filepath)
{
    SDL_Surface *image;
    if ( image = SDL_LoadBMP( filepath.c_str() ) )
    {
        GLuint tex_id;
        glGenTextures( 1, &tex_id );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id );

        glTexImage2D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image->w,
                        image->h, 0, GL_RGB,
                        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels );

        SDL_FreeSurface(image);

        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

        textures.emplace(getFilename(filepath), tex_id);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        return tex_id;
    }
    else
    {
        // std::cout << "[!!] Could not open " << filepath << "! \n";
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The texture is loaded, and then the texture name is placed in a map with the file name as a key. The map is a global defined as `std::map <std::string, GLuint> textures`. I can iterate through the map and verify that GL is assigning texture names properly. Finally, I go on to draw my quads as such:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures["MY_IMAGE.BMP"]);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3d(0.0,  0.0, iNode->verticies[1]);

glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3d(1.0,  0.0, iNode->verticies[2]);

glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex3d(1.0,  1.0, iNode->verticies[3]);

glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3d(0.0,  1.0, iNode->verticies[4]);

glEnd();
```

A few things worth noting:

- Colors for these quads have been defined prior to drawing. If I
  comment out all of the color definitions, which are in format
  `glColor3ub(r,  g,  b)`, the quads render black.
- If I call `glIsTexture(textures["MY_IMAGE.BMP"])`, it returns false.
- The texture names are still stored properly in the map.
- I am using OpenGL 2.1.

Is the texture being somehow deleted internally? Am I doing something wrong with my rendering?

I am willing to supply more code if needed.

**EDIT:**
I have no idea what I did...
Now my renders look like this: [image]

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return anything after the `glGenTextures()` call?

Comment: glGetError reports no error! D:

Comment: Yeah, better post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) then.

Comment: Try dropping a `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` before `glTexImage2D()`.

Comment: No difference. I'll try putting together a SSCCE.

Comment: Does something like [this](http://pastebin.com/WvnZHf9A) work for for you using a 32x32 BMP?

Answer (score 1):

From the [SDL_LoadBMP](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_LoadBMP) documentation:

> Note: When loading a 24-bit Windows BMP file, pixel data points are loaded as blue, green, red, and NOT red, green, blue (as one might expect).

Therefore the format parameter provided to glTexImage2D needs to be `GL_BGR`.